# MDI Child Controls suspend events

Tags: c#, events, mdi

I have a MDI Form with 2 mdi children forms. On both the children forms I have a shared usercontrol (data grid) and the way the usercontrol has to work is exactly the same except for a filter on the one form.

All works well, however, I do have a problem with Events. I created a couple of eventhandlers to detect when things like save/search/load etc happens on the data. However, I don't want both child forms to for example to fire the search event. If I search data on ChildForm1, I dont want ChildForm2 to fire the search event as well.

I tried using Visible and IsAccessible to detect if the usercontrol is on the front of the Mdi forms, but that does not work.

Another option is to see if the parent is the active Mdi form, however, I sometimes have a couple of panels as the parent etc. Which makes it a difficult solution for future development or other scenarios.

Any suggestions?

edit: what I am currently doing is:

```
       private void TransactionLoad_Event(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (loading) return;

        Form parentForm = this.FindForm(); 
        Form mdiParentForm = (Form)this.TopLevelControl; 

        if (mdiParentForm != null && parentForm != null && mdiParentForm.ActiveMdiChild == parentForm)
            LoadTransactions();
    }
```

Thanks Eugene.

Comment: Have you tried to unsubscribe the event for which you don't want it to be handled?

Comment: Code sample could help us help you. I have never went through such situation where two different MDI Children share the same set of events. Perhaps would it serve your purpose to restrict your `ChildForm` to only one instance at a time? You'd have to look whether an instance of `ChildForm` already exist in `ParentForm.MDIChildren`.

Comment: updated post with some code